# Use find to delete directory contents when over 100 MB

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'm having a little trouble getting find to do what I want, here.

What I'm trying to do is delete the files in a directory, when the contents of the directory get to be over 100MB (it's a cache file). I thought I had sussed it out after reading the man page, and a couple other similar but different questions here, but evidently not. If possible, I'd like it to delete only the files that are over 2 days old, but I'm not overly picky about that.

So what I have so far is:

```
$ find .cache/chromium/Default/Cache/ -type d -mindepth 1 -size +100M -mtime 2 -delete
```

But when I try to run it, it gives me the following:

find: warning: you have specified the -mindepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-mindepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

I changed it up to:

```
$ find .cache/chromium/Default/Cache/ -mindepth 1 -type d -size +100M -delete
```

which gave me no warning, but didn't delete a thing.

Any advice/guidance on what I'm doing wrong?

[edit] Currently, the directory is sitting at 433M.

Comment: The directory is at 433M but are there any single files > 100M? And why is `mindepth` set to 1? Are you only interested in files one directory level below the specified path?

Answer (score 4):

Remove `-type d` from your command. With `type d` you are limiting your delete to just directories. The command will never touch files.

```
find .cache/chromium/Default/Cache/ -mindepth 1 -size +100M -delete
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. I'm starting to wonder if the -size +100M is being interpreted as the size of the file to look for and delete, rather than using that as the total size of the files in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `-delete` in `find .cache/chromium/Default/Cache/ -mindepth 1 -type d -size +100M -delete`

Try `find .cache/chromium/Default/Cache/ -mindepth 1 -type d -size +100M -exec rm -rf {} \;` where the `-exec rm -rf {} \;` (needs the ';') passes the results right to an `rm`.

Comment: Hmmm...unless I mistyped, it didn't work...there are still 433 MB in there:

$ find .cache/chromium/Default/Cache/ -mindepth 1 -type d -size +100M -exec rm -rf {} \;

Answer (score 0):

I've already tried to emulate your current scenario here is how I delete files that are already over a 100MB+:

```
find .cache/chromium/Default/Cache/ -type d -print0 | du -h | grep '[0-9]\{3\}M' | cut -f2 | grep -v '^.$' | xargs -I directory rm -rfv directory
```

First of all, why find couldn't be able to find the directory with more than 100MB because a directory when you try to list it --- it would only list for about 4KB (4096). The find command checks only the size of directory --- it does not include the internal files under the directory.

Before you run the command try to do a dry run with it using the *echo* command.

```
find .cache/chromium/Default/Cache/ -type d -print0 | du -h | grep '[0-9]\{3\}M' | cut -f2 | grep -v '^.$' | xargs -I directory echo directory
```

Updated the *-type d* arguments.
Also a bit of update try changing the current working directory to the search path:

```
cd .cache/chromium/Default/Cache/
```

and do the command: (find . -type d -print0 | ... the dry run code here ...).

Comment: Did doing this work for you? I ran into an issue doing it like this - first, it told me that -type needed an option, also that it needed to be after the file path.

So this is how I ran it:

$ find .cache/chromium/Default/Cache/ -type d -print0 | du -h | grep '[0-9]\{3\}M' | cut -f2 | grep -v '^.$' | xargs -I directory echo directory

it listed several directories outside of the Cache directory, so I was a little worried about running it with rm instead of echo.